# How to get ethereum public key

Tags: go-ethereum, public-key

I having the ethereum wallet, how can i generate the public key on that.
Any one have idea about that please share it to me

EDITED VERSION:
I have a local Ethereum wallet, in some form. Given that I know the symmetric key to decrypt the private key, how can I get a plaintext, hexadecimal encoded version of the ECDSA public key?

Comment: Here is a hint: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42055/what-is-the-approach-to-calculate-an-ethereum-address-from-a-256-bit-private-key

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here: Just generate a new account in the Ethereum Wallet and it will display the public key.

Comment: i use the "geth account new" it just give the address only i need the public key